# Placing jitters in the center of the violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I want to draw the black jitters right in the center of the violin plot.
[image]

I am using this code lines

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_violin(trim = F, color ="black")+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.3, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#82a1fa','red'))+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.1, jitter.height = 0))
```

Comment: Use `dodge.width = 0.9` within `position_jitterdodge` to match the boxplots and violins?